# Woocommerce получить id категории по id продукта

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно узнать, к какой категории относится данный продукт, зная id продукта

```
 if( has_term( array( тут id категорий ), 'product_cat', product_id ) {
```

Нашёл данный кусок кода, условие проходит, но что выводить непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [get_the_terms()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_terms) для получения категорий продукта.

```
// Ваш массив категорий
$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
```

Если Вам нужны только ID, используйте [wp_list_pluck()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_pluck) или [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php)

```
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
```